# Recyclerview selected item highlight not works

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I have used Recyclerview with [swipe to delete undo library](https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo). It works fine,but recycler view item selection not works.
I tried to change background color of selected list item.But it does not works.
How to show selected item properly without affecting swipe delete option? Any mistake I have done on my following code?

**MyActivity.java:**

```
    myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this,null);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);

    final SwipeToDismissTouchListener touchListener = new SwipeToDismissTouchListener( new RecyclerViewAdapter(mRecyclerView),new SwipeToDismissTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(ViewAdapter viewAdapter, int position) {
            //mRecyclerView.removeViewAt(position);
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

    // Setting this scroll listener is required to ensure that during ListView scrolling,
    // we don't look for swipes.
    mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener((RecyclerView.OnScrollListener) touchListener.makeScrollListener());

    //mRecyclerView.setActivated(true);

    //mRecyclerView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new SwipeableItemClickListener(this,new com.hudomju.swipe.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Log.i(TAG, "selected  position -> " + position);

            view.setActivated(true);
            view.setEnabled(true);
            view.setSelected(true);
            view.setPressed(true);

            //view.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.list_selector);


            if(view.getId() == R.id.list_item_backside_delete_button){

                // done operations on delete button click    

                touchListener.processPendingDismisses();
            }
            else if(view.getId() == R.id.list_item_backside_cancel_button){

                // done operations on cancel button click    

                touchListener.undoPendingDismiss();
            }
        }
    }));
```

**MyListAdapter.java:**

```
public class MyListAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<MyListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    public MyListAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor){
        super(context,cursor);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView1;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mTextView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_name);

            /*view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });*/

        }


    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
        if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
            String selectedID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Data._ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Data.COLUMN_NAME_NAME));
            viewHolder.mTextView1.setText(name);
        }


    }
}
```

**list_item_view.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    >

</FrameLayout>
```

**list_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/accent" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Try android:state_pressed instead of android:state_activated in your list_selector.xml

Comment: @MarkusRubey tried <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/accent" /> but nothing happens. also tried by setting mRecyclerView.setSelected(true);
        mRecyclerView.setPressed(true); but not works

Comment: Seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo/issues/6) in the library you use.

Comment: Yes,I am trying to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

make global variable to store position and handle click listener in ViewHolder. Onclick of item,change the global position value like

`textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    globalPosition=getAdapterPosition();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });`

then in onBindViewHolder

```
if(postion==globalPosition)
{
    //change color like
    textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
else
{
    //revert back to regular color 
    textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

with this code the item you clicked get red colored and all other wiil be in white